# Check whether an HTML select element has a selected value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a web-page on which I am using jQuery to access the value of a `select` element. When the element has an "empty" value (the value = `""`), I want to *hide a link* elsewhere on the page. Unfortunately - I can't seem to get it working.

Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if ($('#cancelNumber').select().val() == "") {
        $('#ticketsLink').hide();
    } else {
        $('#ticketsLink').show();
    }
});
```

The `div` tags each have a unique ID (already checked for that) - and I have also tried using `===` insetad of `==` - but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cancelNumber is the id of the select html element?

Comment: Clear the .select(), if it's a select, it will bring you the value only with $("his id").val()

Comment: @Adil , its cancelNumber

Comment: Then my answer would work, tell me if any problems

Comment: Please choose one of the answers as correct - or update your question to help us understand how to help resolve your problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `.select()` is just going to fire the `select` event on the `#cancelNumber` element. I think what you're looking for is more akin to:

```
$(document).bind('ready', function () {
    var $cancelNumber = $('#cancelNumber');
    var $ticketsLink = $('#ticketsLink');

    var updateLink = function () {
        if ($cancelNumber.children(':selected').val() == '') {
            $ticketsLink.hide();
        } else {
            $ticketsLink.show();
        }
    };

    // Then assuming you want it to re-update every time the box is changed...
    $cancelNumber.bind('change', function () {
        updateLink();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming cancelNumber is id of select.

*The statement below in you code*

```
$('#cancelNumber').select().val()
```

*Would be*

```
$('#cancelNumber').val()
```

*Your code will be*

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {    
   if ($('#cancelNumber').val() == "") {    
       $('#ticketsLink').hide();    
   }else{
       $('#ticketsLink').show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `.select()`. You just want `$('#cancelNumber').val()`.